# Message not being received by kryonet listener?

Tags: java, junit, kryonet

So I'm having a problem testing my networking, there's a lot of code below but this is as small as I could make an example. The problem I'm having is that it seems the listener I'm registering with the server and client never gets called when when I send a message.

`lock.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` should wait until the message is received or timeout at 5 seconds. However the listener should tell the lock to continue `lock.countDown()` after it sets the `response` variable that prevents the test from failing.

As you can guess, this doesn't happen, the message gets sent, the lock continues due to timeout and the test fails because `response` is null.

```
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;
import com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.fail;

public class TestMessage {
    private Server server;
    private Client client;
    private String response;
    private CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Log.set(Log.LEVEL_DEBUG);

        server = new Server();
        try {
            Log.debug("Binding to port: " + 30454 + "... ");
            server.bind(30454);
            Log.debug("Bound to port" + 30454);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.debug("failed");
            Log.error("Unable to bind to port: " + e.getMessage());
            server.stop();
            fail("Unable to start server");
        }
        Kryo kryo = server.getKryo();
        kryo.register(Message.class);
        Log.debug("Adding server listener");
        server.addListener(new TestListener());
        Log.debug("Starting server... ");
        server.start();
        Log.debug("Server started successfully");
    }

    @Test
    public void testPacketSending() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        client = new Client();
        client.addListener(new TestListener());
        Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
        kryo.register(Message.class);
        client.start();
        client.connect(5000, "127.0.0.1", 30454);

        client.sendTCP(new Message("RECEIVED"));

        lock.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Assert.assertNotNull(response);
    }

    private class TestListener extends Listener {
        @Override
        public void received(Connection connection, Object o) {
            Message m = (Message) o;
            response = m.message;
            Log.debug(m.message);
            lock.countDown();
        }
    }

    private class Message {
        String message;

        Message(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is this:

```
00:00 ERROR: [kryonet] Error reading TCP from connection: Connection 1
com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoNetException: Error during deserialization.
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.readObject(TcpConnection.java:141)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server.update(Server.java:205)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server.run(Server.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (non-static member class): org.glytching.sandbox.kryo.TestMessage$MessageA
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo$DefaultInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(Kryo.java:1308)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstantiator(Kryo.java:1127)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1136)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.create(FieldSerializer.java:562)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:538)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:816)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.read(KryoSerialization.java:55)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.readObject(TcpConnection.java:139)
    ... 3 more
```

Kryonet cannot deserialize into `Message` because (a) it is a non static inner class and (b) it has no public zero-arg constructor. FWIW, there is some [background here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kryo-users/jgAU18bLyN0) on why Kryonet does not support serialisation of non static inner classes.

If you (a) refactor `Message` into its own class or make it static and (b) give it a zero-arg constructor then your test will pass.

The smallest change necessary to make your test pass is to replace this ...

```
private class Message {
    String message;

    Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

... with this:

```
private static class Message {
    String message;

    Message() {

    }

    Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Re this:

> there's a lot of code below but this is as small as I could make an example

The reproduction case in your question was more than adequate, thanks.

Comment: Ah, so all Kryonet message classes need to be static?

Comment: Only if they are **inner** classes.

Comment: Hm, thanks. It seems I've failed to reproduce my issue then since only this example uses inner classes. Maybe it's because my class doesn't have a 0 arg constructor then. How did you get this error output? When I set ```Log.set(Log.LEVEL_ERROR)``` I don't see this output to my console.

Comment: I just ran the test using the code you provided. I made no changes to what you provided. Then, when the issue manifested itself I added the static modified and the zero and constructor and then the test passed.

Comment: I fixed the actual issue, it was because none of my classes had 0 arg constructors.